# Error in compiling hello world example of Opendaylight Fluorine - yang tools issue

Tags: opendaylight, ietf-netmod-yang

I had a working hello-world ODL project on Carbon release. I changed the POM dependencies to the latest version from the public repository and now I am getting a failure while compiling the 'impl' project:

> ```
> cannot access org.opendaylight.yangtools.yang.binding.RpcOutput
> [ERROR]   class file for org.opendaylight.yangtools.yang.binding.RpcOutput not found
> ```

This is due to the source generated by the yang tools in the 'api' project. The sources contain imports of 'RpcOutput' but the 'impl' project does not find it.

I changed my POM in the 'api' project to Carbon and it works fine.

My POM for 'api' project is

```xml
<parent>
    <groupId>org.opendaylight.mdsal</groupId>
    <artifactId>binding-parent</artifactId>
    <!--<version>0.10.4-Carbon</version>--> <--this works-->
    <version>4.0.1</version>  <--this fails-->
    <relativePath/>
  </parent>
```

Versions 4.0.1 and 3.0.6 fail - what has changed in the latest version of ODL and yang tools from the `org.opendaylight.mdsal.binding-parent` project?

The compilation fails in the 'impl' project which is simple:

```java
public class HelloWorldImpl implements HelloService{

    @Override
    public ListenableFuture<RpcResult<HelloWorldOutput>> helloWorld(HelloWorldInput input) {
        HelloWorldOutputBuilder hout = new HelloWorldOutputBuilder();
        hout.setGreeting("hello" + input.getName());
        return RpcResultBuilder.success(hout.build()).buildFuture();
    }
}
```

It fails with the "class file for org.opendaylight.yangtools.yang.binding.RpcOutput not found" error.

The 'impl' project pom is

```xml
 <parent>
  <groupId>org.opendaylight.controller</groupId>
  <artifactId>config-parent</artifactId>
  <!--<version>0.6.4-Carbon</version>--><!--this was the old working--> 
  <version>0.8.4</version>  <!--this is also the latest ver-->
  <relativePath/>
 </parent>
```

The main pom is

```xml
<parent>
   <groupId>org.opendaylight.odlparent</groupId>
   <artifactId>odlparent</artifactId>
   <!--<version>1.8.4-Carbon</version>--><!--this was old working ver-->
   <version>5.0.0</version> <!--this is also the latest ver-->
   <relativePath/>
  </parent>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [the appropriate versions for Fluorine](https://docs.opendaylight.org/projects/integration-distribution/en/stable-fluorine/platform-versions.html):

- `binding-parent` 0.13.2
- ODL Parent 3.1.6

You’ll also need to migrate from `config-parent` to BluePrint, see [the OpenDaylight wiki BluePrint page](https://wiki.opendaylight.org/view/Using_Blueprint) for details. `config-parent` is no longer available in Fluorine.

Since you’re migrating anyway, I would recommend going straight to [Neon](https://docs.opendaylight.org/projects/integration-distribution/en/stable-neon/platform-versions.html). There’s a detailed [guide](https://wiki.opendaylight.org/view/Neon_platform_upgrade) to help you upgrade from Fluorine to Neon.

Comment: Thanks, Steve. I still get the failure. I guess it is due to config-parent reference. Do I have to remove the 'Parent' reference to config-parent from the 'impl' project and use blueprint.  or are there any other references to add in the pom? Is there a latest archetype for new releases - flourine or Nitrogen which creates the blueprint files